# Save custom controls (piece of code) in Visual Studio (2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to share some piece of codes (like snippets) from my ToolBox (to help some developers who don't know well c#). The code was drag-n-dropped from my own code. Can you tell me how to export it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the toolbox can be exported through 'import/export settings'.